# Failed building wheel for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to `pip install pandas==1.2.5`

And have the issue

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

1.Updated pip to the latest version: `pip install --upgrade pip`

2.Tried installing the dependencies for pandas: `pip install numpy matplotlib`

3.Tried installing pandas again: `pip install pandas==1.2.5`